# How to assert if item from response is equal to item from properties

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'd like to make assert to check that data which I sent by REST request with json is equal to item from test case properties. I dont know how to deliver it from test request properties.

Initialy I am traying wrote script assertion like below, but probbaly getProperty doesnt work:

```
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
    def responseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseMessage)

    assert json.items[0].agreementTypeID == testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue('agreementTypeID').toInteger()
```

Comment: do you have any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Script assertion only **context** will work

```
  log.info context.testCase.getPropertyValue("agreementTypeID")
```

// Script assertion **testrunner** will not work

```
  log.info testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue('agreementTypeID')
```

So if you replace the testRunner with context it should work in **Script Assertion** .

[image]

**TestRunner** is available in **Groovy step** and there is a special way of making testRunner available in **Script Assertion** , but above is better

Comment: Works for me. Thx.